# Inner state of embedded types in golang - how does it work?

Tags: pointers, go, methods, struct, embedding

I'm trying to wrap my head around embedding in golang, and I am a bit confused when it comes to the state of a type embedded in another.

Here is my question: If I have a type `Embedii` that is an int, and it has a method that effects its value, should that appear in a type that embeds it?

Here is what I was playing with:

```golang
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

type Embedii int

func (y *Embedii) Do() {
  if y == nil {
    y = new(Embedii)
  } else {
    *y = *y + 1
  }
  fmt.Println(*y)
}

type Embedder struct {
  *Embedii
}

func main() {
  embedii := new(Embedii)
  embedii.Do() // prints 1
  embedii.Do() // prints 2

  fmt.Println("---")

  embedder := new(Embedder)
  embedder.Do() // prints 0
  embedder.Do() // prints 0

  fmt.Println("---")

  nembedii := new(Embedii)
  embedo := &Embedder{nembedii}
  embedo.Do() // prints 1
  embedo.Do() // prints 2
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ArqKESVWoS-

I'm curious to understand why I have to explicitly pass an existing instance of `Embedii` to the `Embedder` type for this to work properly

Comment: `if y == nil { y = new(Embedii) }` probably doesn't do what you think it does. Do not write Javacode in Go.

Comment: Doesn't really resolve your question, but this would achieve all three variants incrementing as expected; https://play.golang.org/p/3aUC412mwsm - Fairly sure your issue is what Volker mentioned. Couldn't say for certain but probably related to remapping the memory address to a new pointer.

Comment: @Mikey that's very interesting, now what I'm curios about is how come the methods of `Embedii` (which are defined with a pointer reference) are added to `Embedder` even though the receiver is a pointer and `Embedii` is included in the `Embedder` struct without the `*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Embedii.Do()` the receiver is a pointer value. It's a copy. Assigning anything to this pointer variable just modifies the copy.

`y = new(Embedii)` just assigns a pointer to the local variable `y`, and when `Do()` returns, it's lost. When called again, `y` will be `nil` again, so it creates and assigns a new value to it (which will be lost again after returning).

It works if you create an `Embedii` prior, because then you don't create and assign it in `Do()` (which would be lost).

If you return the new `Embedii` (more precisely its address) and assign it, you will see it incrementing, but it will start with `0` not `1`, because the first call just creates it without incrementing, and in the other cases it already existed and so first call increments right away:

```
func (y *Embedii) Do() *Embedii {
    if y == nil {
        y = new(Embedii)
    } else {
        *y = *y + 1
    }
    fmt.Println(*y)
    return y
}
```

And using it:

```
embedder := new(Embedder)
embedder.Embedii = embedder.Do() // prints 0
embedder.Embedii = embedder.Do() // prints 1
```

Output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/aZq-x5L8DWt)):

```
1
2
---
0
1
---
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

"should that appear in a type that embeds it?" yes it should, because it is another type inside the struct.